# MySQL: Find out a specific record from a group

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

In the customer table, it has customer_ID, name, sex, age, representative_id. I want to find out the youngest male and female customer for a certain representative.

I have used

SELECT *,MIN(Age) FROM customer GROUP BY Rep_ID, sex;

But it returns the first record of each group. How can I choose a specific row from a group under certain condition? In this case,  age = min(age) for its group. Should I use join? Anyone can give me a hint. Thank you in advance.

```
C_ID    Name        Sex Age Rep_ID
1       Person1     F   26  H3
2       Person2     M   40  H8
3       Person3     M   37  H5
4       Person4     F   51  H5
5       Person5     M   45  H5
6       Person6     F   37  H8
7       Person7     M   27  H8
8       Person8     M   36  H3
9       Person9     F   35  H5
10      Person10    M   30  H8
11      Person11    F   22  H3
12      Person12    F   28  H8
13      Person13    F   19  H3
14      Person14    M   41  H3
15      Person15    M   33  H5
16      Person16    F   34  H3
17      Person17    M   29  H8
18      Person18    F   50  H8
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to look over some MySQL questions and see how you can better format your sample data and query, as it will be much easier for us to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve a problem like this, you first need to find the youngest male/female age for each representative. You can do that by using the `MIN()` function and grouping by sex and rep id like this:

```
SELECT rep_id, sex, MIN(AGE) AS youngestAge
FROM myTable
GROUP BY rep_id, sex;
```

Once you know the youngest age in each group, you can join that subquery back to your original table for the rest of the information:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
   SELECT rep_id, sex, MIN(age) AS youngestAge
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY rep_id, sex) tmp ON tmp.rep_id = m.rep_id AND tmp.sex = m.sex AND tmp.youngestAge = rep.age;
```

For more information on this and problems similar to it, you can reference [this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) page.

Comment: You should only `SELECT m.*` otherwise you'd get all `tmp` fields as well.

Comment: You withheld a vote because I displayed all columns? Pretty high standards. ;P

Comment: @Rainism I'm glad I could help. If this answer remains the solution you use, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer to show future readers what solved your problem.